# LARAVEL: как использовать функцию replace в DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Как использовать функцию REPLACE() в Laravel 5.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод заменяет строку в строке, к примеру у вас выводится текст блога из базы данных и вы хотите заменить какое то слово, это можно сделать функцией replace.

К примеру:

```
<?php
$replaced = Str::of("Наш текст")->replace("То, что нужно заменить", "На что заменить");
echo $replaced;
```